# Is typed properties are global in swift?

Tags: swift, global-variables, type-variables

Is class label properties such as

```
class var brands : [Brand] {
        return [Brand]()
    }
```

are global properties in swift ? I want to create a array of objects as global array in my AppDelegate file and want to access that array from various controller. Can i do it with class label property ?

Answer (score 0):

Any variable or function declared outside of a class body is global. If you want global variable or functions I suggest you create a separate swift file to keep track of what's global across your project.

Example

```
var globalString = "This is global"

func globalFunc() {
    println("This is a global function")
}

class Object {
    var string = "this is not global"
    func myFunc() {
        println("this is not global")
    }
}
```